# Is the source code for the Internet Archive website (archive.org, Wayback Machine) open source and if yes where is the source?

Tags: archive.org

While considering how much I should trust https://archive.org I started looking for its source code.

However, despite expecting it to be open source, due to the not-for-profit open culture nature of the organization, I couldn't easily find the source location.

So, is the source for the website open source, and if yes, where is the source?

The best I could find was the source code for their crawler: http://crawler.archive.org/index.html but I'm guessing this is only one part of the project.

They also have a GitHub organization with several projects: https://github.com/internetarchive but I'm not sure if the most important ones are there. There is a repo https://github.com/internetarchive/wayback though, which is entitled "IA's public Wayback Machine (moved from SourceForge)" and has a two line README.

There appear to be some bug trackers at: https://webarchive.jira.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa although they seem to have little activity as of 2020.

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned, some of the source code is available on https://github.com/internetarchive. This is mainly for projects such as the OpenLibrary.

For the actual code that runs the Internet Archive and the catalog system, it is not open source, although it seems like they host it behind a GitLab instance that they host themselves on https://git.archive.org/explore.